# Programmatically open "Block Settings"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I know when developing a gutenberg plugin I can have user's access the block settings by having them click on the three stacked dots for "More options" and then click on "Show Block Settings". Is there an API/function I can call on to open the block settings instead of having the user go through the "More options"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like for many gutenberg related questions, the [wp data module](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/) is your key to success. There you will find function for selecting blocks and opening sidebars, you will need a combination of both functions.

```
const yourBlockClientId = ''
//select the block you want
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).selectBlock( yourBlockClientId )
//open the edit-block sidebar
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).openGeneralSidebar( 'edit-post/block' )
```

The function to get your blockId is left to you. There are functions to get all blocks with ids in a collection: `wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks()` or to just get the ids `wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlockOrder()`. You will have to get your blockId from there.

Comment: Thank you! The `wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' )` returned an undefined so I was unable to call `selectBlock`. However for my use case I already was in the context of the block, so I had no need to select it. (THANK YOU AGAIN!)